# Use multiple types of upstreams in single unbound.conf

Tags: unbound

Is there a way to specify forwarder type with its address?

Example config I imagine:

```
    forward-zone:
      name: "."
      forward-addr: dot.example.resolver@tls:853
      forward-addr: 192.168.1.2
```